# Border 60 degrees instead of 45 and background color outside div

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble adding gray color to the left of that div.

```
<div class="full-width">
     <div class="footer-nav">
         <div class="footer-nav-left">
              <p class="text-center"> © Copyright 2016. All Rights Reserved </p>
         </div>
         <div class="footer-nav-right">
            Nav links here
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Please check link below for full code:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0sfdypc4/)

What I need is:

[image]

Comment: Add your CSS to your question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 60 deg angle requires uneven borders.

```
.footer-nav-left:after { /* note, now an 'after' */
  content: '';
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 80px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent; /* half border-top */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

For the grey background extending to the left side of the viewport, use another pseudo-element

```
.footer-nav-left:before {
  content: '';
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.full-width {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* no scroll bar */
}
.footer-nav {
  min-height: 80px;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer-nav-left {
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.footer-nav-left:before {
  content: '';
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  /* for demo purposes: use inherit for production */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.footer-nav-left:after {
  content: '';
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 80px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
.footer-nav-left p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="footer-nav">
    <div class="footer-nav-left">
      <p class="text-center">© Copyright 2016. All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-nav-right">
      Nav links here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** the angled border only works (as would any) because the height of the parent is **known**. Percentage width borders are not yet possible.

Comment: Note that you need to change `green` (which is highlighted here for demo purposes) to the gray color that you want.

Comment: Indeed, you can substitute "inherit" for green and it will change automatically. Added note to demo.

Comment: Nice one! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

New css:

```
.footer-nav{
    min-height: 80px;
    width:100%; // <-- changed
    margin:0 auto;
}

.footer-nav-left p{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left: 80px; // <-- changed
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0sfdypc4/1/)

Comment: Hi Darren, the problem is that I can't add width to be 100% since I need it to be 960 and in center of the page no matter which resolution... I've deleted bootstrap classes like container and row to avoid confusion. Also do you have any solution for that border on the right to be different (60) angle?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your border issue;

```
.footer-nav-left p{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left:80px;
}

.footer-nav{
    min-height: 80px;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

.footer-nav-left{
    background-color:gray;
    min-height:80px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:1001;
}
```